# confusing results of pandas boolean operator

Tags: python, pandas, boolean-operations

so, I am trying to analyze a whatsapp message. I tried looking for messages which contain the words "salam" (a), which messages contain both "salam" and "terima" (b), and then which messages contain "salam" but don't contain "terima" (c).

this is the code I used.

```
len(df[(df['message'].str.contains("salam"))])
len(df[(df['message'].str.contains("salam")) & (df['message'].str.contains("terima"))])
len(df[(df['message'].str.contains("salam")) != (df['message'].str.contains("terima"))])
```

[image: this is the amount of the messages above.]

in the image, a = 197, b = 143, and c = 72. Isn't it supposed to be a = b + c? Or perhaps `!=` isn't the `NOT` operator I should've used? Does anyone have any idea what did I do wrong?
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Use `~` like `len(df[~((df['message'].str.contains("salam")) & (df['message'].str.contains("terima")))])`

Comment: Thank about what effect '!=' gives you. In this context it will give you an exclusive or so the total will be those messages that contain either 'salam' or 'terima' but not both.  So if a message contains 'terima' but not 'salam' it will be included in the count. These messages will not be counted in a or b. Indeed it seems to me that there are 22 such messages.

Comment: oh i see. thank you so much! I used ``` ~ ``` in the wrong way, and I mistook ```!=``` for ``` NOT ```, instead of ``` XOR ```.